# Approach to flexibly access encapsulated data objects / how to analyse performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, data-access

Today I thought of a highly flexible way to access data-sets, that are encapsulated using closures.

I'm still writing my WebGL stuff, so my resulting example is related to it (coordinates / rotation state). Nevertheless it's easily transferable to other contexts. Please have a look at this:

```
function RandomObject(x, y, z){
    var rotX = 0;
    var rotY = 0;
    var rotZ = 0;

    this.data = {
        "position" : {
            set: function(position){x = position[0]; y = position[1]; z = position[2];},
            get: function(){return {"x": x, "y" : y, "z" : z};},
            x: function(value){return value? (x = value) :  x;},
            y: function(value){return value? (y = value) :  y;},
            z: function(value){return value? (z = value) :  z;},
            readOnly: true
        },
        "rotation" : {
            set: function(rotation){x = rotation[0]; y = rotation[1]; z = rotation[2];},
            get: function(){return {"x": rotX, "y" : rotY, "z" : rotZ};},
            x: function(value){return value? (rotX = value) : rotX;},
            y: function(value){return value? (rotY = value) : rotY;},
            z: function(value){return value? (rotZ = value) : rotZ;},
            readOnly: false
        }
    };
}
```

My purpose is to access the data of objects generated with this constructor like this:

```
var set = "position";
var coordinate = "z";
object.data[set][coordinate](5);
```

The readOnly thing is just for checking if users should be able to modify those values. And yes, I could refactor those `return value? (x = value) :  x;` lines, but I thought it's more readable without another function.

First question: did you find something that could go very wrong when using this?

Second question: do you know better approaches to handle such a situation?

Third question: what about performance, will this require way more ressources compared to normal standard getters / setters? Do you have any idea how to benchmark this?

Thanks for reading and your suggestions.

---

To clarify that: I don't want to write the worlds fastest JavaScript appication, but I just don't want memory <strike>leaks</strike> troubles to show up, when I instance .. let's say about 200-300 of those objects.

Comment: Yes, you really should refactor this, as there is something that goes very wrong: You cannot set your values to `0`!

Comment: Why do you use getters/setters at all if a) you don't care about `readOnly` b) you don't do validation or something c) you care about performance?

Comment: Thank you Bergi, I knew I forgot something important, lol. Of course I would hide readOnly, too later, that were just a few quick keystrokes right before I opened this question. Encapsulation is in my mind a very needful thing, when writing big object oriented applications. That code snippet was just a general frame for what's in my mind, so that's no productive code without any validations for that sake. Is it a crime to be motivated, to produce well separated as well as high-performance code at the same time? :D

Comment: Hm, I just don't see parts of your `.data` object you are trying to encapsulate here using getters/setters. How do they benefit the separation (of whatever)?

Comment: Re your clarification: memory leaks don't have anything to do with this. Yes, if you use getters/setters (whether native or with methods) it will take more memory (though few enough that it is negligible, especially when you only instantiate a few hundred objects), but they don't [leak memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Comment: Until now it's just a semantic thing. But I want to have clear and flexible interfaces and accessors between the modules of my application and "whatever" (may come). I know what a memory leak is, I'm just not that familiar with the way of how JavaScript handles memory especially when there are closures or nested classes, so I was afraid of having built something like a JavaScript blend of Windows Vista.

Comment: OK, my take at this is YAGNI. Putting data property names down makes an as clear and flexible interface for me as does putting setter/getter method names down.

Comment: It doesn't. Imagine you are developing inside a team. It would be horrible, if everyone could access every property of any class someone else has written. Of course you could make use of conventions (the famous "_") or documentation. But that's not that safe. Offer someone the ability to use your code in an unintended way an he will do it. Another point is maintainability / expandability: Data-logic and structures may change, but the accessors / interfaces should always offer the expected results. By just using public attributes, code gets gluey as hell over time.

Comment: Only that in your example, it seems to be intended that everyone can access all fields of `data` - there is no internal structure that needs to be hidden. And if you really need to use such in the future, you still can change your property to be accessors.